# Make a node double its size on mouse over in sgma.js

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I am having a bit of a hard time understanding how sigma.js handles the size of nodes and edges.

I get that you set a `minNodeSize` and `maxNodesSize` in the graph's setting. Actual display size is then assigned depending on the node's individual size as well as the level of zoom of the graph. Correct?

What I am trying to achieve is that a node doubles its size on a mouseOver, and shrinks back to the original size on a mouseOut. Here is my code:

```
var minNodeSize = 1;
var maxNodeSize = 5;

sigma.parsers.json('giantComponent.json', {
      container: 'graph',
      settings: {
        minNodeSize: minNodeSize,
        maxNodeSize: maxNodeSize
      }   

      //Assign same size to all nodes
      var s = sigma.instances()[0];
      var nodes = s.graph.nodes();
      nodes.forEach(function (n) {
          n.size= maxNodeSize/2;
      })
    }
    );

//Function to change a nodes size on mouseOVer
function interactiveNodes () {  
    var s = sigma.instances()[0];
    var nodes = s.graph.nodes();
    s.bind('overNode', function (d) {
        d.data.node.size = maxNodeSize;
        s.refresh();
    })
    s.bind('outNode', function (d) {
        d.data.node.size = maxNodeSize/2;
        s.refresh();
    })
    }
```

Result: when I hover on a node that node stays the same size while all other nodes shrink to half their size.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking for the autoRescale option.
https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Settings#global-settings

Comment: Yes indeed I managed to solve it through this `autoRescale: ['nodePosition', 'edgeSize']` ... [credits to Yomguithereal](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/774)